# How to plot an histogram from 'groupby' and 'mean' functions

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this:

[image: Imgur]
with different country name.
I want to compute the mean of the *Medium height* column and group by the *Country* column; then i want to plot an histogram with the name of all countries on the xticks.

To do that i calculated the mean with: `height = df.groupby(["Country"]).mean()["Medium Height"]`
and the i tried to plot the histogram with:

```
plt.hist(height, density=1, facecolor="black", alpha=0.6)
plt.xticks(countries, df["Paese"])
```

but the plot looks like this:
[image: Imgur]

This is the code i used:

```py
height = df.groupby(["Country"]).mean()["AMedium Height"]
countries = np.arange(152) # The number of countries
plt.hist(height, density=1, facecolor="black", alpha=0.6)
plt.xticks(countries, df["Country"])
plt.show()
```

-- EDIT --
Here's a portion of the dataframe i used:

```
       Country  Year  Height
0  Afghanistan  1870   168.4
1  Afghanistan  1880   165.7
2  Afghanistan  1930   166.8
3      Albania  1880   170.1
4      Albania  1890   169.8
```

Comment: Can you create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating your problem? Prepare an example of `df` with portion of your data, e.g. `df.head()`

Comment: The first image is the output of _df.head()_

Comment: Yes. To make an MVCE you need to convert it into smth. like: `df = pd.DataFrame([("Afghanistan", 1870, 168.4), ("Albania", 1870, 190)], columns="Country Year Weight".split())`. Help community to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to draw a bar plot of mean height vs countries.

you can do this

```
means = df.groupby(["Country"]).mean()['Height']
print(means)
```

results in

```
Country
Afghanistan    166.966667
Albania        169.950000
Name: Height, dtype: float64
```

and then plot it like this

```
ax = means.plot(kind = 'bar')
ax.set_ylabel('Mean Height')
```

results in

[image]

if you want all the bars to be same color use

```
ax = means.plot(kind = 'bar', colors = 'grey')
ax.set_ylabel('Mean Height')
```

which results in

[image]